# How do I bookmark a Question/Answer?

Tags: support, faq

I've found a question I'm interested in - how can I receive updates of when it gets answers or updates?

Comment: [What is a favorite question? How do they work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/53585/54262)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## Questions

If you find an interesting question, one that pertains to you, or that you just want to monitor. You can add it as a Favorite. Doing so will provide you with a notification each time you login via the Message icon next to your name at the top.

To favorite a question simply click the star on the left side of the question under the Down-vote option.

[image: Unstarred]

When you favorite a question the star will turn gold and the total number of favorites will be increased by one.

[image: Starred]

To remove yourself from receiving further notifications simply click the start an additional time and it will return to it's original state.

## Answers

There currently is no way to "favorite" an answer. However you can directly link to an answer to recall it again later. At the bottom of an answer there are a series of options - one being "link".

[image: link]

After clicking link the URL to page you are browsing will be updated to reflect a direct link to that answer.

Comment: Can you get email notifications for the favourite  questions updates?

Answer (score 4):

On the bottom right of the question page there is a feed link:

[image: screenshot]

This will be updated with new answers and edits to the question or answers.

Though this isn't a traditional bookmark, it's a great way to receive updates.  I've been using a single feed group/category for questions much like bookmarks.