# Separation of Q&A feed to specific topics

Tags: feature-request, feeds

What do you think about separation of Q&A feed to specific branches, like Ask Ubuntu Hardware Q&A, Software Q&A, Drivers, Games and so on ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There does already exist a separation between different questions based on Tags which are applied to questions. These help in the separation of questions in different categories. I do not think another level of separation is required.

Answer (score 3):

You can already get a feed for a specific tag (the link is on a [tag page](https://askubuntu.com/tags/hardware) in the same location as [question feed links](https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/588)).

If you want a group of related tags, you can use an [SE tag set](http://stackexchange.com/tagsets).